# mongodb $dayOfYear equivalent Unix epoch time aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a method of grouping a Unix epoch time by day, equiv to $dayOfYear

or a process of aggregating floats, ints (into quartiles, hundreds, thousands, %)

try to avoid map reduce but an example of it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost but not quite use Unix time seconds in aggregation pipeline by utilizing the $mod and $divide operators.

The math is Unix time seconds / 86400 to convert seconds into days since Epoch. Then modula that result by 365.25 for the day of the year (leaps every 4).

So the full aggregation for $dayOfYear using seconds is almost as simple as

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate( {$project : {"day" : {$mod : [  {$divide : ["$unix_seconds", 86400] } , 365.25] }  } },  { $group : { _id : "$day" , num : { $sum : 1 } } }   , {$sort : {_id : 1}}  )
```

The above adds sorting for sequential day of year.

The problem is that the $mod operator returns both the whole number and remainder. and there is no way of rounding or truncating the remainder. Therefore the results are grouped by whole and remainder.

```
            {
        "_id" : 235.1864887063916,
        "num" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 235.24300889818738,
        "num" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 235.60299520864623,
        "num" : 3
    },
    {
        "_id" : 235.66453935674085,
        "num" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 235.79900382758004,
        "num" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 235.80265845312474,
        "num" : 1
    },
```

.. when clearly we want only the whole number

```
    {
        "_id" : 235,
        "num" : 8
    },
```

What would be nice is a $trunc or modula returning only the whole ($modw), and mod returning only remainder ($modr) operators in mongo.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object which would be available to any server side JavaScript processing for MapReduce functions.

You seem to be aware of the [$dayOfYear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/#exp._S_dayOfYear) operator in the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). There are [other operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline-operator-reference) there for processing dates.

Unless your needs are very specific you **should** be using the aggregation pipeline. It is very flexible and in most cases will be considerably faster than the equivalent actions run under mapReduce.

Comment: yes. agg pipeline is what im seeking. the issue: the data is formatted as seconds not a datetime

Comment: Which is why I first pointed you at the `Date` object for JavaScript which can be constructed from epoch time. You cannot cast your value into a date type in aggregation so you will be stuck with MapReduce. The full explanation is for the benefit of others who do have dates and should be using the aggregation pipeline. If **you** want to use aggregation, you need to convert to dates. They are actually just epoch time internally anyhow.